# Named pipes error 40, connecting to Xampp through visual studio

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio-2012

I have set up Xampp as a server to host my database.

I am trying to connect to the database, filter results and output them to the datagridview based on the text in txtSearch

```
 private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=epas;Persist Security Info=True;uID=root;Password=Password");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Description, Retail FROM pricing where ID like'" + txtSearch.Text + "%'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

However everytime I run it I get the same error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

If I enter the wrong details I cannot get access, but I have altered the connection string multiple times and can not get connected

I am using updated Xampp and visual studio 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok stupid question time, xamp is apache, mysql, php and perl. So are you trying to connect to a mysql database. If so you are using the wrong data adapter you are using a mssql data adapter you would be wanting the mysql one eg https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.8.html

If you are connecting to a mssql database eg one of the express editions please disregard.